# web pack, missing module error

Tags: javascript, webpack, angular-components

New to webpack and using a yeoman scaffolded project. I want to us angular-prompt in a component in a 1.5 angularjs project, so here's what I've done

1) npm install angular-prompt --save

2) Added: import prompt from 'angular-prompt' to app.js

3) Added: angular-prompt to the vendor array in webpack.make.js

When the app is rebuilt, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "angular-prompt"
```

What gives? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add it to your angular modules? `angular.module('your_app', ['ui.bootstrap','cgPrompt']);`

Comment: Yes, I did. I took it out trying to narrow down the problem. I get the same error, since no doubt, the module is not resolved to begin with, its presence in the module declaration is irrelevant until the module is actually resolved.